# Is it possible to trade Pokémon on HeartGold without using WEP?

Tags: nintendo-ds, pokemon-fourth-generation

Yes, there is already a similar question here, but it's not the same.

Situation:

1. WEP connections are not a good idea.
2. There's no-one around who owns another 3DS and a Pokemon game.

My question is: does this mean that there's no way for me to actually trade Pokémon?

I understand it only works with a Wifi connection secured with WEP - is that correct?

So if I don't have that, is there no other way?

Comment: I'm not sure, but is it even possible to trade over internet, considering the Wii and DS online services have been shut down?

Comment: Unsecured WiFi connections work as well.

Comment: I used to use this USB connector back when the services still worked, since I had exactly the same issue as you. http://www.amazon.co.uk/USB-Access-Point-Nintendo-Wii/dp/B000BVAPFI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've hit the nail on the head with that one. Original Nintendo DS games only support WiFi networks secured with a WEP key, or open WiFi networks.

However the underlying issue here is that there is nobody around with another DS/3DS and Pokemon game for you to trade with. Even if you had a WiFi connection, you could only use it to trade locally with someone else on the same WiFi.

If, somehow, you were able to get your hands on another DS/3DS and another game of the same generation, then you could use it to trade locally via WiFi. Almost all (if not all) consumer routers support opening the WiFi network by disabling security altogether. Consult your router's documentation or online resources (using the router's model number) on how to do this. The simplest solution is to back up your existing security information, setting it as an open network for the trade, then setting the security back onto the router.

Comment: So even if I changed my network's security to WEP, I still wouldn't be able to play with anyone who ISN'T on the same network - is that correct?

Comment: Correct, it would **have** to be on the same network.

Comment: Well, thanks for confirming for me these sad news :(

Comment: One more question, if you don't mind: does the wifi have to be connected to the internet for that to work?